# Setting a customized option in a stored procedure

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, plpgsql, postgresql-9.5

I'm trying to set a custom option in a stored procedure, but it is storing the variable name and not contents of the variable.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION set_user(_user_id bigint, is_local boolean default true) returns void AS $$
BEGIN
  SET my.user_id TO _user_id;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;

select set_user(1);
select current_setting('my.user_id');
 current_setting 
-----------------
 _user_id   
(1 row)
```

I expect `current_setting` to return `1`, not the string value `"_user_id"`.

Comment: There is already a function for this: `set_config()`: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-SET

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I tried `set_config()` but it only works with text

Comment: I'm rather certain that custom variables (`my.user_id`) are also stored as text. I can't find a reference for that however

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/config-setting.html  It seems logical they would be all text in the actual config file, however I'm using custom options which seem to hold their type

Comment: `SET my.user_id TO 1;` followed by `show my.user_id;` returns a text column so I would say they do not preserve their type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### First solution

Syntax for `SET` is:

```
SET [ SESSION | LOCAL ] configuration_parameter { TO | = } { value |'value' | DEFAULT }
```

where `value` is the new value for a given `configuration_parameter`.

In order to assign a value stored in `_user_id` variable, you need to generate a dynamic command and then [`EXECUTE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN) it.

This would be the way to do that:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION set_user(_user_id bigint, is_local boolean default true) 
RETURNS void 
LANGUAGE PLPGSQL
AS $$
BEGIN
  EXECUTE 'SET my.user_id TO ' || quote_nullable(_user_id);
END;
$$;
```

Attaching [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/ca750/1) link for testing purposes.

**Note:**

- [`quote_nullable()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html) function would return `NULL` if the input argument is null. It may not be necessary in your case.

---

### Second solution

You could also achieve the same thing with [`set_config()`][4] function as @a_horse_with_no_name noted. Your function would then look like that:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION set_user(_user_id bigint, is_local boolean default true) 
RETURNS void 
LANGUAGE PLPGSQL
AS $$
BEGIN
  PERFORM set_config('my.user_id', _user_id::TEXT, false);
END;
$$;
```

Attaching [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/da55f/1) link for testing purposes.

**Note:**

- You have to **explicitly cast** the second argument to a **varchar** type
- [`PERFORM`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-SQL-NORESULT) is used to evaluate an expression and discard the result since it's not needed
- You could use `quote_nullable()` function here as well

Comment: Another option is to simply use `set_config()`: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-SET

Comment: you don't need PL/pgSQL for that. A plain SQL function will be faster.

Comment: Are you sure that these statements are available in plain SQL functions?

Comment: Absolutely. It's a "normal" SQL function. You can call it anywhere you can write SQL statements, including other SQL functions.

Comment: I've tried it myself, and it yields errors at `EXECUTE` and at `PERFORM` respectively for both solutions. I believe they are not available in plain SQL function.

Comment: Well `perform` indeed is only available in PL/pgSQL. But can simply put a `select set_config('my.user_id', _user_id::TEXT, false);` into a SQL function. >ou have to change the return type from `void` to `text` though. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/a7cde/1

Comment: I agree, just wanted to keep it as it was in OP question (return type).

Comment: `set_config` is ok as long as you are only dealing with text values, then you can drop the `::text` cast and support nulls better, etc.