# How can I properly update value of my row after it has been updated

Tags: postgresql, sql-insert, audit-logging

I'm trying to track how my data are changed,

I am working with custom solution because I will track those changes only when I run the script.

What is most important to me is to have `previous_value` and `value_after_update`

```
INSERT INTO audit_details 
    (updated_table, updated_column, query, value_before_update, value_after_update)

SELECT 'some_table', 'some_column', query, enabled, (Here I've tried to put same query as it's contained on update because that value will be there after update),
FROM some_table WHERE product_id = _new_product_id;


UPDATE some_table
SET enabled = CASE WHEN (SELECT 1 FROM some_table WHERE enabled = true AND product_type = T1.product_type AND product_id = ANY(_previous_product_ids)) IS NOT NULL
    THEN true
    ELSE enabled END,
    THEN true
    ELSE accepted END
WHERE product_id = _new_product_id;
```

As you can notice guys, **problem is that I don't know how can I properly insert also** `values_after_update`, I should somehow repeat
block from update into my insert into above (I have tried it even If I couldnt run it, it was big and ugly XD) ?

Any kind of help would be awesome!

Thanks

Cheers

Comment: Instead of doing the `SELECT`, you can use `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` to get the ID of the last inserted row btw

Comment: @JamesS: there is no `scope_identity()` in Postgres. Did you mean `lastval()`?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Could you provide me an example with lastval() or how is it called, I'm like 5 days on sql in general. Thanks for help!

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I seen the sql tag and assumed it was that

Comment: @JamesS: there is also no `scope_identity()` in "SQL"

Comment: @MateuszRek: is `product_id` a primary or unique key?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name it's foreign key to products table

Comment: And if you update 5 columns for 10 rows, do you want 50 rows in `audit_details` (one for each changed column and row) or  just 50 rows that contain the information about all changed columns?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name one row, one column.. For each column add one row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with one single statement chaining multiple [CTEs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING), that captures the old value and new value before and after the UPDATE.

Then you can "iterate" over the columns by converting the rows to JSONB and extracting the changed values.

```
with old_data as (
  -- collect the old values
  select id, to_jsonb(t) as old_value
  from some_table t
  where product_id = 100
), new_data as (

  -- this is where the actual UPDATE is done
  -- change the SET part as you need it
  update some_table
     set enabled = false,
         some_value = 4
  where product_id = 100
  -- this returns the modified values from the CTE
  returning id, to_jsonb(some_table) as new_value

), changed_column_values as (
  -- this converts the JSON values into one row per column
  -- and selects those column values that have changed
  -- it is assumed that the column some_table.id is the primary key 
  select nd.id, x.*
  from new_data nd
    join old_data od using (id)
    join lateral (
      select nd.id, n.col as column_name, o.value as old_column_value, n.value as new_column_value
      from jsonb_each_text(nd.new_value) as n(col, value)
        join jsonb_each_text(od.old_value) as o(col, value) on o.col = n.col and n.value is distinct from o.value 
    ) x on x.id = nd.id
)
-- now insert the result of the previous comparison into the audit table
insert into audit_details (updated_table, updated_column, query, value_before_update, value_after_update)
select 'some_table', column_name, old_column_value, new_column_value
from changed_column_values
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=5c331e35bbbc24e910099c53ac724701)

---

While the above code works, it's pretty ugly and prone to errors just to catch the changes for a single UPDATE statement.

I would use one of the many ready-made generic auditing solutions that can be found [here](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/tracking-changes-in-postgresql/) or [here](http://okbob.blogspot.co.uk/2015/01/most-simply-implementation-of-history.html) or [here](https://www.garysieling.com/blog/auditing-data-changes-postgres) and attach the generic trigger only to those table where you need it.

Or extend the trigger function to check for e.g. a [configuration setting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29469454/330315) and only store the changes if the property is set to e.g. `true`. Then if you want to "debug" your statements turn on the audit logging (`set session ....`)  and turn it off afterwards. You can also create a function for that, similar [to this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36293944)

Comment: I'm really new to databases and everything and this helps a lot! I  Can you explain little bit why did you convert rows to JSONB? I will try to study this now! I can say THANKS A LOT! :)

Comment: one more question sir, I tested it and it really works! Thanks!  If any column of the update statement changes this will insert new row into audit_details table, how could I say track only enabled column, and for any other don't insert new row in audit table? Thanks a lot one more time! Maybe I could add where on changed_column_values for example where column_name <>'column_to_avoid';